# Grouping values from list into buckets to keep sum of values at or below threshold

Tags: python

I have a list of times in minutes that represent the time it takes to do some job, but the amount of time spent working cannot exceed 240 minutes in any given day.I would like to separate into N groups such that the sum of the items in the group does not exceed the threshold (240 in this example).

An example list could be `[60, 70, 90, 120, 180, 240]`

One possible solution to the above list would be:
`[[240], [180, 60], [70, 90], [120]]`. Note how each of the sums in each list does not exceed the threshold of 240 while leaving some leftover is fine, but how do I know this is the most optimal solution? Optimal being defined as simultaneously minimizing leftover and the number of buckets.

I've been working on trying to do this with some `for` loops in Python but it feels about as inefficient as possible. Also, due to the method of removing items from the list, the `for` loop isn't iterating over all values. Below is my attempt.

```
import random
import math

def roundup(x):
    return int(math.ceil(x / 10.0)) * 10

threshold = 240;

randomlist = []

for i in range(0,10):
    n = random.randint(30,240)
    randomlist.append(roundup(n))

days = []

print (randomlist)

for item in randomlist:
    schedule = []
    schedule.append(item)
    minutes_remaining = threshold - item
    for item2 in randomlist:
        if randomlist.index(item) != randomlist.index(item2):
            if item2 <= minutes_remaining:
                minutes_remaining -= item2
                schedule.append(item2)
                randomlist.remove(item2)
    randomlist.remove(item)
    days.append(schedule)

print (days)
```

Comment: Would another way of putting what you're looking for be that you want to determine all of the subsets of `[60, 70, 90, 120, 180, 240]` whose sums do not exceed 240?

Comment: That’s exactly right. Well said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from itertools import permutations, product, accumulate

THRESHOLD = 240


def make_groups(lst, n):
    """
    Make n groups. The sum of the items in the group does not exceed 
    the threshold.
    """
    groups = []
    grps_range = [range(1, len(lst) - n + 2) for _ in range(n)]
    combo = [i for i in product(*grps_range) if sum(i) == len(lst)]
    for c in combo:
        marker = [0] + list(accumulate(c))
        group = [tuple(sorted(lst[i:j])) for i, j in zip(marker, marker[1:])]
        conform = [sum(g) <= THRESHOLD for g in group]
        if all(conform):
            groups.append(tuple(sorted(group)))

    return groups


def ngroups_leftover(entry):
    """
    Returns number of groups and sum of left over times
    """
    ngroups = len(entry)
    leftover = [THRESHOLD - sum(x) for x in entry]
    return ngroups, sum(leftover)


groups = []
l = [60, 70, 90, 120, 180, 240]
perm = permutations(l)
for p in perm:
    for i in range(1, len(p) + 1):
        result = make_groups(p, i)
        groups += result

unique_groups = set(groups)

x = sorted(unique_groups, key=ngroups_leftover)
# There are many solutions which result in the same number of groups
# and left over time. But, the first entry would do.
print(x[0])
```

Output

```
((60, 180), (70,), (90, 120), (240,))
```

All possible combinations:

```
[((60, 180), (70,), (90, 120), (240,)),
 ((60, 70), (90, 120), (180,), (240,)),
 ((60, 180), (70, 120), (90,), (240,)),
 ((60, 90), (70, 120), (180,), (240,)),
 ((60, 120), (70, 90), (180,), (240,)),
 ((60, 70, 90), (120,), (180,), (240,)),
 ((60, 180), (70, 90), (120,), (240,)),
 ((60, 180), (70,), (90,), (120,), (240,)),
 ((60,), (70, 90), (120,), (180,), (240,)),
 ((60, 70), (90,), (120,), (180,), (240,)),
 ((60,), (70, 120), (90,), (180,), (240,)),
 ((60, 120), (70,), (90,), (180,), (240,)),
 ((60, 90), (70,), (120,), (180,), (240,)),
 ((60,), (70,), (90, 120), (180,), (240,)),
 ((60,), (70,), (90,), (120,), (180,), (240,))]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import permutations 

l =[60, 70, 90, 120, 180, 240]

perm = permutations(l)

results = []
for p in perm:

    for i in range(1, len(p)):
        if sum(p[ : i]) <= 240:    
            results += [ tuple( sorted( p[ : i] ) ) ]

print(list(set(results)))
```

The printout is:

```
[(90,), (90, 120), (60, 70, 90), (180,), (60,), (120,), (60, 180), (240,), (70,), (70, 120), (60, 90), (70, 90), (60, 70), (60, 120)]
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a Greedy solution `O( N log(N) + N)`, not sure if it is Optimal.

```
inp = [60, 70, 90, 120, 180, 240]
inp.sort()

i =0
j = len(inp)-1
k = 240
while j >= i:
    tmp = []
    tmp.append(inp[j])
    sm = inp[j]
    while i < j:
        if sm + inp[i] > k:
            break
        sm += inp[i]
        tmp.append(inp[i])
        i+=1
    print(tmp)
    j-=1
```

Output:

```
[240]
[180, 60]
[120, 70]
[90]
```

Comment: I'm realizing now that my approach does not scale well, so hoping to achieve the most optimal solution is probably not worth the trouble. Running a list of 10 items using `permutations` ran for 10 minutes before I killed it. In practice, there will be hundreds of data points so I need to rethink my strategy. Your code runs and appears to scale quite a bit better.

Comment: @MatthewSnell I think your problem falls under the category of NP-Hard problem, so going for an exponential solution (like permutation) may give you an optimal solution. Still, if you are looking to scale it, you need to look towards approximation or greedy solutions.